# youtube search by keyword internal working

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Need a clarification on this:

As per [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) "By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel, and playlist resources", how this matching takes place, do they search on comments also, any idea on this.

Thanks !!

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] I would like to see the code you are using.

Comment: @DalmTo, any idea on above part ?

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube api operates on the same rate limits as the other google apis.

There are project based limits and user based limits.

[image]

You can see the limits on google developer console.

My project can make a max 1800000 requests per minute

It also has a quota cost limit of 10000 which is not really what it sound like.

Then each  user can make a max of 180000 request per minute.

This not related to the amount of data a user  has on their account.  Its strictly related to the number of requests or the cost of the request your application or a user can make over a period of time.

You can request additional daily quota over the development 10k if you want.  Just submit the form over on google cloud console.

Comment: Any idea on above ?

Comment: Not sure what idea you are looking for.  If you need more quota request more.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of increased abilities with YouTube APIs for *big* YouTube channels.

Comment: Any idea on above ?

Comment: @AbhinavBatta [You just changed completely your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74508483/revisions), instead of modifying that way your question, just ask another question on StackOverflow with a new post. By the way AFAIK they don't search with comments too.